# The maximum number of moves in a game of Nim

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory

I was assigned a fun, but also quite hard problem for my computer science class - I have to write a java program that computes the maximum number of turns in an optimal game of Nim.

In case you are not familiar with the game, you can read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim).

In this case, we are only interested in winning positions for player A - we do not care about scenarios where player B is victorious. The idea is quite simple: We have *N* heaps with *n1, n2, ... nn* elements. Player A wants to remove *m* elements from a heap of his liking in such a way that the **nim sum** (*n1 ⊕ n2 ⊕ ... ⊕ nn*) **equals 0**. After that player B makes his move (which can never result in nim sum being 0 for the second time in a row). Then player A repeats the process of removing elements from one of the heaps in such manner that nim sum is set to 0. This back and forth will eventually result in player A taking the last element of the final non-empty heap and thus winning.

​

I have to calculate the maximum possible number of turns it takes for player A to win. There are 2 important rules that must always be satisfied:

- **Player A will always try make the best possible move,**
- **If player B finds himself in a lost situation, he will try to prolong the game for as long as possible.**

​

Through my time analyzing this problem, I've come to the following assumptions:

- **The best move for player A is to always remove the maximum possible number of elements that he can, while still passing the nim sum of 0 to player B,**
- **The best way for player B to prolong the game is to remove 1 element at the time,**
- **Player B should always remove a single element from a heap with the most elements left at the time of his move.**

​

I'd love to hear your corrections, opinions and observations regarding these 3 statements, as I have no mathematical proof for them, they are based solely on some program testing and observation.

Comment: Assignments for computer science classes are off-topic here on MO, where the intention is to discuss questions of mathematical research.

Comment: It seems to me that, in the position $(6,5,3)$, removing one element from the heap of $6$ loses faster than removing one from the heap of $5$ or the heap of $3$.